# Load Output into a file / perl

Tags: perl

I'm counting the number of times different names occur in a folder of *.htm files. How do I get a `system "grep..."` call to write to the output file instead of the screen?

I've had this working when printing to screen.  As soon as I tried to write it to file, I get the names and a 0 written to file and the counts from grep written to screen.  I've found some good advice to help me get this far, but now it's getting specific I'm finding a lot of "noise" in the search results.  Any pointers to tutorials relevant tutorials are most welcome.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (INFILE, '<', "names.txt");
open (OUTFILE, '>', "report.txt");

while (my $row = <INFILE>) {
    chomp $row;
    my $name = "$row";
    my $number = system "grep -o $name *.htm | wc -l";
    print OUTFILE "$name\t $number\n";
}
close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

I'm expecting something like this in the OUTFILE

```
Name1  245
Name2  198
Name3  79
```

What I get in OUTFILE

```
Name1   0
Name2   0
Name3   0
```

What I get on the SCREEN

```
245
298
79
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html): "This is *not* what you want to use to capture the output from a command; for that you should use merely backticks or `qx//`, as described in [`\`STRING\``in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60_STRING_%60)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **system** function runs the command and returns the STATUS CODE of the command i.e if it was successful, it will return 0, else will return error code.

What you want to do is use **backtick** operator to capture the **STDOUT** of the command instead of system.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (INFILE, '<', "names.txt");
open (OUTFILE, '>', "report.txt");

while (my $row = <INFILE>) {
    chomp $row;
    my $name = "$row";
    my $number = `grep -o $name *.htm | wc -l`;
    print OUTFILE "$name\t $number\n";
}
close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

Comment: The line `my $name = "$row";` serves no purpose.

Comment: You should also take care as this code allows lines from names.txt to execute arbitrary shell.